# PHP Cross Application Login validation

Tags: php

I have a sample app (say app1) with Username and password fields.. when the users submit the value, the credentials need to be verified with another website login page(say app2), if app2 login succeeds then i will redirect to the home page of app1...

Is it possible via PHP?

Comment: I think you should implement something like oauth http://oauth.net/

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is. You need to execute a curl request to site2 with data included. Then check the result. If login operation is successful you can redirect your user.

```
//You have recived username and password in post method, now it is time to log user in site2
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/login.php');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'login='.$_POST['login'].'&password='.$_POST['password']);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'full path cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'full path cookie.txt');
$page = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);

//If he typed in wrong password, on site2 should be some error.
$error_text = 'Incorrect login or password'; //Text that will show on site after unsuccessful login attempt

//Check if is there any error on site2
if (strpos($page, $error_text) !== false) {
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/'); //Everything seems to be ok, when do you want to redirect user?
} else {
    echo 'You typed in incorrect username or password';    
}
```

Comment: Hello Helid, I am new to PHP, your explanation looks good.. but can you please delve a bit further.. and give me some more lines of code with comments ! Thanks

Comment: ok cool now ! can you pl explain this line ; curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'login='.$_POST['login'].'&password='.$_POST['password']);

Comment: Hello Helid - How to verify if the user is trying to type on Page-2.. can you show that in your code, I mean the USername,password and button fields in Site2.. Can you help out please...?

Comment: I don't undestand what exactly you have in mind. 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'login='.$_POST['login'].'&password='.$_POST['password']);

This line send POST data to site2 to log user in site2. I can't say much more if I don't know the site that we are talking about. Anyway I forgot about one important thing. You will probably have to receive cookies from site2 so you need to add
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'full path cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'full path cookie.txt'); and create cookie.txt file.